# Need This Type of animation using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

This animation was generated in premier pro but i want to create it in ffmpeg:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried, and what didn't work? Please [edit] and update your answer.

Comment: Create animated subtitles using Aegisub and burn that using subtitles filter. See https://sub-sub-gakkou.livejournal.com/6604.html

Comment: use drawtext to create the text....what is ffmoeg?

Comment: @RicardoBohner sorry by mistake its ffmoeg its ffmpeg 
but how to achive this in drawtext

Comment: @nikhil verma can you give more details on size of background image, font, font size, speed? in this example I used a black background 700x500 fontsize 50 color green and speed 1,5 seconds to go from right to center, then wait 1,5 and next text: https://i.imgur.com/bh2432Z.gif

Comment: Transparent backgroud: https://i.imgur.com/Fw2TLX8.png

Comment: Are you talking about the sliding effect, or that part that makes the text look like it is beeing slided in several different horizontal strips or both?

Comment: @RicardoBohner ya sir i m talking about the sliding effect and every time text slide its change

Answer (score 0):

This would be a one-liner with the options I described in the comments:

```
 ffmpeg -f lavfi -t 1.5 -i color=size=700x500:color=Black -loop -1 -filter_complex "[0]drawtext=text=This is the 1st Text:font=Arial Black:y=(h-line_h)-15:x=(w)-t*((W+tw)/2)/1.5:fontcolor=green:fontsize=50[Part1];[0]drawtext=text=This is the 1st Text:font=Arial Black:y=(h-line_h)-15:x=(W-tw)/2:fontcolor=green:fontsize=50[Part1_];[0]drawtext=text=This is the 2nd Text:font=Arial Black:y=(h-line_h)-15:x=(w)-t*((W+tw)/2)/1.5:fontcolor=green:fontsize=50[Part2];[0]drawtext=text=This is the 2nd Text:font=Arial Black:y=(h-line_h)-15:x=(w-tw)/2:fontcolor=green:fontsize=50[Part2_];[0]drawtext=text=This is the 3rd Text:font=Arial Black:y=(h-line_h)-15:x=(w)-t*((W+tw)/2)/1.5:fontcolor=green:fontsize=50[Part3];[0]drawtext=text=This is the 3rd Text:font=Arial Black:y=(h-line_h)-15:x=(w-tw)/2:fontcolor=green:fontsize=50[Part3_];[Part1][Part1_][Part2][Part2_][Part3][Part3_]concat=n=6:v=1:a=0[Final]" -map [Final] -compression_level 6 -loop 0 "My Text.gif"
```

I also made a batch script that creates a "png", "webp" and a "gif" animation. Please safe the following code into notepad, next save it with the name that you want but with a *.bat extension:

```
@echo off

set FileName=Text Animation
set BackgroundColor=black
set BackgroundSize=700x500
set TextColor=green
set TextBorder=pink
set TextFont=Arial Black
set TextSize=50
set Speed=1.5
set Text1=This is 1st Text
set Text2=This is 2nd Text
set Text3=This is 3rd Text

if exist "palette.png" del /q "palette.png"

cls
echo.
echo  Creating PNG Animation...
ffmpeg -f lavfi -t %Speed% -i color=size=%BackgroundSize%:color=%BackgroundColor%,format=pix_fmts=yuva420p -loop -1 -filter_complex  "[0]drawtext=text=%Text1%:font=%TextFont%:y=(h-line_h)-15:x=(w)-t*((W+tw)/2)/%Speed%:fontcolor=%TextColor%:borderw=1:bordercolor=%TextBorder%:fontsize=%TextSize%[Part1];[0]drawtext=text=%Text1%:font=%TextFont%:y=(h-line_h)-15:x=(W-tw)/2:fontcolor=%TextColor%:borderw=1:bordercolor=%TextBorder%:fontsize=%TextSize%[Part1_];[0]drawtext=text=%Text2%:font=%TextFont%:y=(h-line_h)-15:x=(w)-t*((W+tw)/2)/%Speed%:fontcolor=%TextColor%:borderw=1:bordercolor=%TextBorder%:fontsize=%TextSize%[Part2];[0]drawtext=text=%Text2%:font=%TextFont%:y=(h-line_h)-15:x=(w-tw)/2:fontcolor=%TextColor%:borderw=1:bordercolor=%TextBorder%:fontsize=%TextSize%[Part2_];[0]drawtext=text=%Text3%:font=%TextFont%:y=(h-line_h)-15:x=(w)-t*((W+tw)/2)/%Speed%:fontcolor=%TextColor%:borderw=1:bordercolor=%TextBorder%:fontsize=%TextSize%[Part3];[0]drawtext=text=%Text3%:font=%TextFont%:y=(h-line_h)-15:x=(w-tw)/2:fontcolor=%TextColor%:borderw=1:bordercolor=%TextBorder%:fontsize=%TextSize%[Part3_];[Part1][Part1_][Part2][Part2_][Part3][Part3_]concat=n=6:v=1:a=0[Final]" -map [Final] -y -compression_level 6 -plays 0 -f apng "%FileName%.png" 1>nul 2>nul

echo.
echo  Creating WEBP Animation...
ffmpeg -i "%FileName%.png" -loop 0 -c:v libwebp_anim -y "%FileName%.webp" 1>nul 2>nul

echo.
echo  Creating GIF Animation...
ffmpeg -i "%FileName%.png" -vf palettegen=reserve_transparent=1 -y "palette.png" 1>nul 2>nul
ffmpeg -i "%FileName%.png" -i "palette.png" -lavfi paletteuse=alpha_threshold=128 -gifflags -offsetting -y "%Filename%.gif" 1>nul 2>nul

if exist "palette.png" del /q "palette.png"
exit
```

Next you can play a bit around with this options and see what you get, for example to get transparent background instead of black use BackgroundColor=#00000000@0.0 you also can use HTML codes...

```
set FileName=Text Animation
set BackgroundColor=black
set BackgroundSize=700x500
set TextColor=green
set TextBorder=pink
set TextFont=Arial Black
set TextSize=50
set Speed=1.5
set Text1=This is 1st Text
set Text2=This is 2nd Text
set Text3=This is 3rd Text
```